# How do I create a counter within a method of a class

Tags: python-3.x, python-class

I can't get into a lot of detail as this is for a homework assignment but I need to create a class that has a method with a counter. When I call the object, I need the counter to increase by 1 for every . However whenever I use the below code, the counter only ever gets increases to 1 and stops.

How do I get the counter to keep increasing and how do I get the counter to save the number it stopped at and if I call the object again get it to keep increasing?

```
String = 'ABCEDFGABCDEFG'

class MyClass():
   def __init__(self):
     self.counter = 0 

def MyMethod(self, String):
   for letter in String:
     if letter == "A":
       self.counter += 1
     else:
       pass
    return self.counter

MyObject = MyClass()
MyObject.MyMethod()
```

So in this case I'd be looking for MyObject = 2 (counter number) but if I called MyObject again in a later piece of code, I'd want MyObject = 4

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: The value of the counter stops at 1, but I'd need it to stop at 2 as there are two A's in the string. But also, I need the counter variable to "remember" it's value, so if I call the object again I get the value of 4. Not really sure how to go about this

Comment: Well, the code you have at the moment can't work because you missed out a `def` and you didn't create any instances. So if you have some other code which gives you the result 1 when you expect the result 2, you need to edit that into your question.

Comment: Is the `MyMethod` method supposed to be inside the class? If so, then the indentation is wrong. Anyway after fixing that (and adding `String` to the method call), the code will return 2 so I don't see the problem...

Comment: `MyMethod` is not indented correctly to be a method of `MyClass`; it's just a regular function.

Comment: What do you mean "call the object"? Instances of `MyClass` are not callable.

Answer (score 1):

You must indented correctly for method `Myclass`:

```
String = 'ABCEDFGABCDEFG'

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0 

    def MyMethod(self, String):
        for letter in String:
            if letter == "A":
                self.counter += 1
            else:
                pass
        return self.counter

MyObject = MyClass()
print(MyObject.MyMethod(String))
```